# 1980s Novel, Runner takes performance enhancing drug to win races

Tags: story-identification, drug

While watching the Olympics, I recalled a book I read in the late 70s or early 80s. (Pretty sure I read it about the same time I read the 1977 novel "Goldengirl" by Peter Lear)

A runner is approached by a doctor with a new type of performance enhancing drug. (not steroids) I don't remember the specifics, but maybe it was a metabolism enhancer as opposed to a muscle mass enhancer. (You had to keep taking the drug, as it built up slowly maybe over a period of months, to full effect, and if you stopped gradually wear off over a few months.)

So after he starts taking it he starts easily winning National and International Events. He even has to slow himself down so it not so obvious how much better he is.

I seem to recall one longer race where he was timing it so he was running 1 minute laps for the whole race, and for the final lap ran it in 30 seconds, and won.

There were some side effects that he noticed from the drug. The only one I recall is he noticed his cuticles on his fingernails grew so that a third of his nails were covered by the cuticles.

I am not sure but I think the "Doctor" was giving the drug to one athlete in dozens of sports (a swimmer, a basketball player, soccer player, etc)

Finally, I think he starts noticing some serious side effects, (Maybe his trainer/coach starts mentioning individual athletes in various sports who are having major medical conditions/dying?) and tells the doctor he is **not** taking it anymore, because it's too dangerous.

Over the next few months he starts slowing down as it wears off, but hopes he will still be able to be a top contender in future races.

The book ends (maybe at the Olympics since he qualified from his earlier wins) where he is lined up on the starting blocks with the other international athletes, and notices the runners on either side of him both have their cuticles covering a third of their fingernails. (It appears they are on the drug.)

Comment: Are you sure this is a novel? It sounds more like a short story. It doesn't seem to have enough meat on it to make up a complete novel unless there are extra plot elements that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Pretty sure it was a novel. Another plot point might have been that his girlfriend was also a test subject (she was in another sport) who had a bad side effect, thus his wanting to stop taking it, but I cant be sure. His trainer/coach was more involved, (but was not initially aware of his taking the drug) who was pushing him to train, because after he started taking the drug and winning, he did not need to train, but did not want to tell his trainer/coach why he was not training anymore.